# How gmail come to know that if user is trying to access it from a browser or from other application?

Tags: python, browser, gmail

I've made one program in Python using Web.py to access my gmail account. It gave me following error in beginning "Please log in via your web browser and then try again." Then I went to gmail security settings and enable it for accessing gmail from less secure apps. It started working fine from the program I've developed.

( Security Setting link: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)

My question is how Gmail comes to know that from where I am trying to access it? Also, if you can share similar scenarios with me where you have to access something via web browser only?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

when you access gmail,maybe the http protocol is used,in http protocol header,User-Agent represent our browse and operation system information.Hope this helpful

Answer (score 0):

Is the gmail account a normal account or your own domain? If its ur domain then you need to login and change the outbound relay section in settings.

[unlock captcha will help to fix this problem](https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha)

Another way simple way is if you go to the email after trying to access without browser a yellow notification will tell you that something tried to access your account.Follow steps and you may have whay you want.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: @Rajat please mark the answer useful or accepted if your problem was solved or it help to move forward :)